# SQL, how to join three tables with no xref in second table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have three tables in below format:

Table_1

```
Plan_ID  Plan_Code   Plan_Description  Location_ID
 1          A           Plan A             1
```

Table_2 (Currently now rows)

```
ID   Plan_ID  Procedure_ID   Discount
```

Table_3

```
Procedure_ID   Procedure_Name  Procedure_Fee     Location_ID
   1                 P1             10              1
   2                 P2             20              1 
   3                 P3             30              1
   4                 P3             30              2
```

So I need to write a query which outputs below result when Plan_Id is passed and also by matching Table 1 and 3 Location_ID:

```
Plan_ID  Plan_Code   ID   Procedure_ID  Procedure_Name  Procedure_Fee Discount
   1          A       0        1               P1            10          0
   1          A       0        2               P2            20          0
   1          A       0        3               P3            30          0
```

Also in Table_2, if we have a cross reference rows

```
ID   Plan_ID  Procedure_ID   Discount
 1      1          2            5
```

Below should be the query output:

```
Plan_ID  Plan_Code   ID   Procedure_ID  Procedure_Name  Procedure_Fee Discount
   1          A       0        1               P1            10          0
   1          A       1        2               P2            20          5
   1          A       0        3               P3            30          0
```

So far I have tried :

```
declare @planID int =1 
SELECT t1.Plan_ID, 
    t1.Plan_Code,
    t2.ID,
    t3.Procedure_ID,
    t3.Procedure_Name,
    t3.Procedure_Fee,
    t2.Discount
FROM table1 tl
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 
    on t1.Plan_ID=t2.Plan_ID  
RIGHT JOIN table3 t3 
    ON t2.Procedure_ID  = t3.Procedure_ID and t1.Location_Id=t3.LocationID
where t1.Plan_Id = @planID
```

But because of `where` condition, query does not output any result but when i replace `where` condition in first join, I get incorrect output. I have tried running query with different table sequence and join option but could not succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since table 2 may or may not have a matching row, you need to handle the missing data in the matches between table 1 and table 2:

```
declare @planID int = 1;

SELECT t1.Plan_ID, 
    t1.Plan_Code,
    if(t2.ID IS NULL,0,t2.ID) as `ID`,
    t3.Procedure_ID,
    t3.Procedure_Name,
    t3.Procedure_Fee,
    IF(t2.Discount IS NULL,0,t2.Discount) as `Discount`
FROM table1 tl
JOIN table3 t3 
    ON t1.Location_Id = t3.LocationID
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 
    ON t2.Procedure_ID  = t3.Procedure_ID and t1.Plan_ID = t2.Plan_ID  
where t1.Plan_Id = @planID;
```